# Validation Exception - the right way to handle

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, validationexception

I am trying to validate the postal code in my but the approach i am thinking of is not working out and I can't understand why.

I created a Validator, that hast to throw a `ValidationException` if it's not valid.

```
@Service
public class ZipCodeValidator{

    public void validate(String zipCode){
        validateNotEmpty(zipCode);
        validateHasNoSpaces(zipCode);
    }

    private void validateNotEmpty(String zipCode){
       if (zipCode.length() != 0){
           throw new ValidationException("Postal Code can't be empty");
       }
    }

    private void validateHasNoSpaces(String zipCode) {
        if (zipCode.contains(" ")){
            throw new ValidationException("Postal Code can't contain spaces");
        }
    }

}
```

In my service, where i receive the postal code I want to throw my custom exception (to which i pass the error message) like this:

```
    try{
        validator.validate(zipCode);
    }catch (ValidationException ex){
        throw new ZipCodeValidationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

However it doesn't seem to work, that exception is not caught so the program runs further.

What am I doing wrong?

Is the whole approach wrong? What would you recommend?

Here's my custom Exception

```
public class ZipCodeValidationException extends Exception{
    public ZipCodeValidationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: u should use Exception rather than ValidationException everywhere.

Comment: where are you trying to validate ZipCode inside Controller ? there is specific place if you are doing it inside controller

Comment: @silentsudo it is currently happening in the service that i call from the controller. But i am quite a Junior, so i have no idea if that's the way to do it.

Comment: can you show the `zipCode` code value ? looks like there is bug in your code @Diana

Comment: @Deadpool the value of zipCode is `""` , after I changed `ValidationException` to `Exception` my code started doing what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @Diana Just a suggestion on a different point. In case you have the liberty to use third party libraries, you could use the StringUtils.isBlank() function from Apache lib, to perform these simple String validations. 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: why are you suggesting third party library, isn;t this sufficient?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.Object- and also https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#hasLength-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: @silentsudo yes agree, the ones that you have posted would be more apt ,since they belong to Spring. Its just that Apache utility libs are also pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

- to process all exceptions in universal place as `ExceptionHandler` class, for more details see: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
- you can extend `ValidationException` from `RuntimeException`, that approach will allow unloading the code from try-catch constructions
- @Service annotation is not quite right for converters or validators, as rule @Service class contains business logic, for helpers classes will be better use @Component, in total no differences between these two annotations only understanding which layer of application that component has

Please share the code for more suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please find my answer in 2 steps, first the correct and then the second the suggested way to implement.

**Correction:**

Please use `ObjectUtils.isEmpty(arg)` for checking if string is 0 length or null. Here is the modified version of your code

```
public interface ZipcodeService {
        void validate(@Zipcode String zipCode) throws ZipCodeValidationException;
    }

    @Service
    public static class ZipcodeServiceImpl implements ZipcodeService {
        private final ZipCodeRegexMatcher zipCodeRegexMatcher;

        public ZipcodeServiceImpl() {
            zipCodeRegexMatcher = new ZipCodeRegexMatcher();
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(String zipCode) throws ZipCodeValidationException {
            // uncomment for Regex Validation
            // boolean valid = zipCodeRegexMatcher.isValid(zipCode);
            // uncomment for Simple text validation
            final boolean valid = !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(zipCode);

            if (!valid) {
                throw new ZipCodeValidationException("Invalid zipcode");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how the caller looks like from `Controller`

```
@GetMapping(path = "dummy")
    public String getDummy(@RequestParam("zipcode") String zipCode) {
        try {
            zipcodeService.validate(zipCode);
            return zipCode;
        } catch (ZipCodeValidationException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Suggested way:**

add following entry to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Create Annotation and Validator as given below

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ZipcodeValidator.class})
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Zipcode {
        String message() default "Invalid Zipcode value";

        Class<?>[] groups() default {};

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }

    public static class ZipcodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Zipcode, String> {
        private final ZipCodeRegexMatcher zipCodeRegexMatcher;

        public ZipcodeValidator() {
            zipCodeRegexMatcher = new ZipCodeRegexMatcher();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String zipCode, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            return zipCodeRegexMatcher.isValid(zipCode);
        }
    }
```

Once this setup is done, head over to Controller class and annotated class with
[@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) and field you want to have validation on with the Custom Annotation i.e `Zipcode` we have just created. We are creating a Custom Validator in this case ZipcodeValidator by extending [ConstraintValidator](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/validation/constraintvalidator).

This is how the caller looks like:

```java
    @GetMapping
    public String get(@Zipcode @RequestParam("zipcode") String zipCode) {
        return zipCode;
    }
```

On Failed validation, it throws `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: get.zipCode: Invalid Zipcode value` which you can customize according to your need by using [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html).

You can also use `@Zipcode` annotation at the service level and it works the same way. Regarding `ZipCodeRegexMatcher` instead of creating it inside the constructor you can create a bean and inject that dependency. It is a simple class that has regex for [zipcode](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/us-postal-zip-code-validation/) and performs validation.

```java
public static class ZipCodeRegexMatcher {
        public static final String ZIP_REGEX = "^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$";
        private final Pattern pattern;

        public ZipCodeRegexMatcher() {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(ZIP_REGEX);
        }

        public boolean isValid(String zipCode) {
            return pattern.matcher(zipCode).matches();
        }
    }
```

The entire code is located [here](https://gist.github.com/silentsudo/26aa39eaf7c5a0235e89469d809ab9d3)